# How to get values that are not directly in the list?

Tags: c#

I want to get the values from a list based on the selected day. I know this is vague but keep reading to understand.
 I have two lists, rooms and fullList.

Rooms consists of just room numbers/names:

```
7-04
7-05
7-06
7-07 (Small Conference Room)
7-08
Large Conference Room
```

fullList consists of a concatenation of a few strings (the '#' is used as a delimiter, also the room is the same as above list):

```
event_id + "#" + text + "#" + eventStart + "#" + eventEnd + "#" + repeat+ "#" + Days + "#" + room + "#" + startDate);
```

A simple input in the fullList is show as:

```
"3#CISC3345#10:45#13:00#0#Monday:Wednesday#7-08#10/03/2014"
```

What I want is a new list in that for each room I want to get the time before eventStart and after evnetEnd, with a boundary of "9:00" and "22:00".

So example:

Example data looks like is this (each row is a value in fullList):

```
Event_ID    Event       EventStart  EventEnd    Days               Repeat Rooms   DayStarts
  2         CISC 3660   09:00:00    12:30:00    Monday               1    7-07     9/19/2014    
  4         MATH 2501   15:00:00    17:00:00    Monday:Wednesday     0    7-04     10/13/2014   
  5         CISC 1110   14:00:00    16:00:00    Monday               1    7-07     9/19/2014    
  7         CISC 1340   15:00:00    22:00:00    Monday               1    7-08     9/19/2014
```

I want to get the times that aren't in between the eventStart and eventEnd.

ex. For SelectedDate (9/19/2014) the list should return:

```
Room  FreeTimeStart  FreeTimeEnd
7-07   12:30:00       14:00:00
7-07   16:00:00       22:00:00
7-08   09:00:00       15:00:00
```

ex2. SelectedDate (10/13/2014):

```
Room  FreeTimeStart  FreeTimeEnd
7-04    9:00:00       15:00:00
7-04   17:00:00       22:00:00
```

Comment: You should change `fullList` from a string to an class which has fields such as `eventId`, `text`, `eventStart`, etc.. This will make filtering much easier.

Comment: ok, then how would i get the other(result) list?

Comment: You first have to do what @David is suggesting. Also, tell us where you are getting the values like `event_id` from.

Comment: Once you have made the change David suggests, then the result list is easily constructed by retrieving the items from the source list for the selected date, setting your initial start time to 12am on the selected date, the initial end time to the first start time of the elements in your list of items for that date, and then iterate through the items list, returning new start/end pairs for the gaps between those elements. The use of an iterator method will likely make implementation a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FullList {
    public int ID              { get; set; }
    public string Event        { get; set; }
    public string Text         { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventEnd   { get; set; }
    public string  Days        { get; set; }
    public int Repeat          { get; set; }
    public string Room         { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate  { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() {
        return ID + "#" + Text + "#" + EventStart + "#" + EventEnd + "#" + Repeat+ "#" + Days + "#" + Room + "#" + StartDate);
    }
}

public class FullListCollection : List<FullList> {

    public List<FullList> FindByStartEnd (DateTime start, DateTime end) {
        return this.FindAll(x => x.EventStart >= start && x.EventEnd <= end);
    }
}

// in the client class, assume we have a populated FullListCollection
myEventList // our list of events
FullListCollection EventsInDateRange = myEventList.FindByStartEnd ( <somestartdate>, <someenddate>);
```